# Laravel Eloquent - Using pivot table's id as a foreign key in another table

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot

LARAVEL 5

I have a table that's belong to few other tables , at the moment of add new recored into it need all other table's id too , the tables structure are :

agreement-table:

- user_id,
- Client_id,
- Owner_id,
- property_id,
- date ,
- ....( all other columns no related to this conversation )

User-table:

- id,
- ...

Client-table:

- id,
- Role ( which can be client or Owner)
- ...

property-table:

- id,
- ...

what is the right way to make relation with agreement-table? and how can I insert/update data into agreement-table?

what are the Model/Controller?

I tried to update it manually in this way but it just insert 0 into records : ( the data send by post or session all working right but not able to insert into database).

```
 $agreement= new RentalAgreement(array(

        'client_id'         =>  Session::get('client_id'),
        'owner_id'          =>  Session::get('owner_id'),
        'property_id'       =>  $request->property,
        'user_id'           =>  Auth::user()->id,
          .
          .
          .
```

this is the database migration :

```
Schema::create('rental_agreements', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('client_id');
        $table->integer('owner_id');
        $table->integer('property_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0):

for the manually update just need to add the columns name to the model's `$fillable` list this

```
$fillable=[ 'client_id','user_id',........ ];
```